# Collision not detected in method OnCollisonEnter2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm trying to detect collisions but they are not triggered:

```
public class cs_bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisonEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        Debug.Log("collision");
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "target")
        {
            Debug.Log("hit_target");
            Destroy(coll.gameObject);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

**Bullet prefab**

[image]
[image]

**Target prefab**

[image]
[image]

Comment: How exactly do you move your object(s)? Have you tried putting a `Rigidbody2D` also on your target object? Try using `Continues` instead of `Discrete` for the collision detection of the Rigidbody

Comment: FYI, it's recommended to use `coll.gameObject.TagCompare('tag')` instead of `coll.gameObject.tag == 'tag'` - https://answers.unity.com/questions/200820/is-comparetag-better-than-gameobjecttag-performanc.html

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you need to type the method as "OnCollisionEnter2D" and not like "OnCollisonEnter2D"(You missed the 'i' in the name).